# Can we conclude that there are more people in a random group of milion with trait A rather than B having only met two and knowing they both have A?

Tags: probability

I think we cannot. I've tried writing it down on paper unsuccessfully because I am not sure how to calculate the joint probability that someone has A and two people do have A. I am also not sure if the chance that two people really have A is the probability of exactly 2 successes in the binomial experiment B($10^6$,P(A)) or the sum from 2 to $10^6$ successes. Note that we don't know anything about P(A) and P(B) besides that there are no other traits.

Comment: You are right but you can try to solve it using certain assumptions

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this using only 10 people

Event (E): getting to pick 2 A

Sample Space(S): (0,10)(1,9)(2,8)(3,7)(4,6)(5,5)(6,4)(7,3)(8,2)(9,1)(10,0)

Event (M): A > B

To find out P(M/E):$\frac{P(M \cap E)}{P(E)}$

Assumption: All the cases of sample space S are equally likely to occur

P$(E)$= $\frac{(0+0+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{7}{2}+\binom{8}{2}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{10}{2})}{\binom{10}{2}}$*$\frac{1}{11}$ = $\frac{0+0+1+3+6+10+15+21+28+36+45}{495}$= $\frac{165}{495}$

P$(M \cap E)$= $\frac{(\binom{6}{2}+\binom{7}{2}+\binom{8}{2}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{10}{2})}{\binom{10}{2}}$*$\frac{1}{11}$ = $\frac{15+21+28+36+45}{495}$= $\frac{145}{495}$

P(M/E) =$\frac{145}{165}$=$\frac{29}{33}$

Note: In this case suppose you were given the probabilities of P(A) and P(B) than instead of using the assumption of equally likely and multiply by $\frac{1}{11}$, you have to multiply each case with their weighted quantity.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by (0,10)(1,9)...

Comment: Sample space (S) list all the possibilities of 10 people. You can have  1 A and 9 B people with traits or (2A  8B) (3A 7B) etc